# Is there a Google Maps API for iOS or any other web service which offers Deals, Offers based on location information?

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-location

I am trying to build an app which shows deals and offers based on users location on the maps.

Can you please let me know any web service or any API which exposes deals, offers based on current or user location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think foursquare is providing the API for deals and offer but I am not sure. That you have to search & do some R&D.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not used MKMapKit API of the iOS?

Comment: I am looking for web service or any API which exposes deals, offers based on current or user location. can you please help on this!

Comment: For this you need to create webservices and maintain a database according the location

Comment: that is well understood, but instead of working from scratch. There should be some site exposing its services for deals or offers.